# fortmatting text python, use of floats?

Tags: python

I am trying to format a table with values but feel i am doing it in a bad way. For instance having to convert a dictionary of ints to an int when dividing and passing into the string. And also %f seems to print loads of 0's. I just want a division with a decimal point, not all the trailing 0's

```
band1= {'channel1': 10564, 'channel2': 10589, 'channel3': 10612, 'channel4': 10637,'channel5': 10662, 'channel6': 10687,
'channel7': 10712, 'channel8': 10737, 'channel9': 10762, 'channel10': 10787,'channel11': 10812, 'channel12': 10837, }


print '%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s' % ("Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3",
"Channel 4", "Channel 5", "Channel 6", "Channel 7","Channel 8", "Channel 9", "Channel 10", "Channel 11", "Channel 12")
print '%10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s' % (band1['channel1'], band1['channel2'], band1['channel3'],
band1['channel4'], band1['channel5'], band1['channel6'], band1['channel7'], band1['channel8'], band1['channel9'], 
band1['channel10'], band1['channel11'], band1['channel12'])
print '%5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f' % (int(band1['channel1'])/5.0, int(band1['channel2'])/5.0, int(band1['channel3'])/5.0,
int(band1['channel4'])/5.0, int(band1['channel5'])/5.0, int(band1['channel6'])/5.0, int(band1['channel7'])/5.0, int(band1['channel8'])/5.0, int(band1['channel9'])/5.0, 
int(band1['channel10'])/5.0, int(band1['channel11'])/5.0, int(band1['channel12'])/5.0)
```

This gives:

```
Channel 1  Channel 2  Channel 3  Channel 4  Channel 5  Channel 6  Channel 7  Channel 8  Channel 9 Channel 10 Channel 11 Channel 12
    10564      10589      10612      10637      10662      10687      10712      10737      10762      10787      10812      10837
2112.800000 2117.800000 2122.400000 2127.400000 2132.400000 2137.400000 2142.400000 2147.400000 2152.400000 2157.400000 2162.400000 2167.400000
```

Comment: If you have a bunch of values in a dict and want to format and print them out the same way, then consider our sanity and follow the best practise of looping through the dictionary, in this case with `for x in band1`. It's far more readable and easier to edit.

Comment: @Hiroto All right will give it a try, my problem is how to do this in the first place, reduce repetition.

Answer (score 4):

```
rows = zip(*((key, value, value/5.) for key, value in sorted(band1.items(), 
                                           key= lambda x: int(x[0][7:]))))

print '\n'.join(''.join('{0:<10}'.format(elem) for elem in tup) 
                                               for tup in rows)
```

out:

```
channel1  channel2  channel3  channel4  channel5  channel6  channel7  channel8  channel9  channel10 channel11 channel12
10564     10589     10612     10637     10662     10687     10712     10737     10762     10787     10812     10837    
2112.8    2117.8    2122.4    2127.4    2132.4    2137.4    2142.4    2147.4    2152.4    2157.4    2162.4    2167.4
```

Broken into pieces:

```
cols = [(key, value, value/5.) for key, value in sorted(band1.items(), 
                                        key= lambda x: int(x[0][7:]))]
print cols
# [('channel1', 10564, 2112.8), ('channel2', 10589, 2117.8), ('channel3', 10612, 2122.4), ('channel4', 10637, 2127.4), ('channel5', 10662, 2132.4), ('channel6', 10687, 2137.4), ('channel7', 10712, 2142.4), ('channel8', 10737, 2147.4), ('channel9', 10762, 2152.4), ('channel10', 10787, 2157.4), ('channel11', 10812, 2162.4), ('channel12', 10837, 2167.4)]
rows = zip(*cols)
print rows
# [('channel1', 'channel2', 'channel3', 'channel4', 'channel5', 'channel6', 'channel7', 'channel8', 'channel9', 'channel10', 'channel11', 'channel12'), (10564, 10589, 10612, 10637, 10662, 10687, 10712, 10737, 10762, 10787, 10812, 10837), (2112.8, 2117.8, 2122.4, 2127.4, 2132.4, 2137.4, 2142.4, 2147.4, 2152.4, 2157.4, 2162.4, 2167.4)]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain your answer a little? I dont follow some parts like `(*(` what is the * for? and some other parts

Comment: @Paul -- it's tuple unpacking - `zip` takes a generator that yields columns as tuples and returns a list of rows as tuples...

Comment: @Paul -- I broke some of it down into pieces that should make it more understandable... Also, what output do you want if you have more that one decimal point? do you want to strip it off even if its not zeros?

Comment: Ah I see thank you, much clearer. Why do you sort it? Would it not be in that format anyway? It will only every have one decimal point to be valid but if it had more then I would like it to show any non zero.

Comment: @Paul - python dicts are not ordered so you need to sort the items (returns a list of tuples) based on channel numbers (keys) to get the right order. (as for decimal points, this should do what you want)

Answer (score 1):

`round(your_float, decimal_point)` will solve your problem.

Example:

`my_float = 3.5678009`

`rounded = round(my_float, 2)`

`print rounded`

--> 3.57

Comment: If I do something like this it doens't work:  round(int(band1['channel12'])/5.0,2)

Comment: Works for me. `round(int(band1['channel12'])/5.0,2)` prints `2167.4`.

Comment: Odd, it mustnt work for me because I am passing it in like so: print '%5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f %5f' % (int(band1['channel1'])/5.0, int(band1['channel2'])/5.0, int(band1['channel3'])/5.0,
int(band1['channel4'])/5.0, int(band1['channel5'])/5.0, int(band1['channel6'])/5.0, int(band1['channel7'])/5.0, int(band1['channel8'])/5.0, int(band1['channel9'])/5.0, 
int(band1['channel10'])/5.0, int(band1['channel11'])/5.0,  round(int(band1['channel12'])/5.0,2))

Comment: I don't see any `round` methods in that expression.

Comment: @Kevin I don't see any DRY methodology in it, either

Comment: @Hiroto You mean there is repitition? that's the problem, I don't think this is the best way to be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If every result numbers are guaranteed to have only 1 decimal point with trailing zeros, Then you can:

**use [String Format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) :**

```
>>> i = 2112.800000
>>> print "{0:5.1f}".format(i)
2112.8
```

**Alternatively :**

```
>>> i = 2112.800000
>>> print "%5.1f" % i
2112.8
```

Comment: You can't do something like this? `print "{0:5.1f}".format(int(band1['channel1'])/5.0)`

Comment: thanks, that works, now to try to do it well for multiple values.